# Knockout.js: Set radio button value onload

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radio-button, form-control

Please see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/priests1234/ga6fb5ke/1/)

I have a couple of radio buttons and depending if one of them is selected I want a text box to then show. I have been able to achieve this using knockout.

What I want to happen is when the page loads, if the value of the "Timesheet" radio button is checked I want the text box to show. But I've been unable to work out how to do this. Thanks is advance.

See below my knockout code:

```
function K2ConsultantApprovalViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.timeSheetSelected = ko.observable("");
}
ko.applyBindings(new K2ConsultantApprovalViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `checked` binding is applied to a radio button, it will set the element to be checked when the parameter value equals that of the radio button element's `value` attribute. So you need to slightly change your way of thinking and create a "payment type" observable that stores the chosen payment type, rather than the boolean "is timesheet selected?" observable that you have now. You can then initially give this observable the value "Timesheet", and that will be what is selected on page load. It also makes it trivial to show or hide any other elements based on the current selection.

```
function K2ConsultantApprovalViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.paymentType = ko.observable("Timesheet");
}

ko.applyBindings(new K2ConsultantApprovalViewModel());
```

And binding would look like this:

```
<input id="DisbursementsOrTimeSheet_ChoiceField0" type="radio" name="DisbursementsOrTimeSheetChoice" value="Disbursements" data-bind="checked: paymentType">
```

Update Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/ogx37up6/).

#### Update

I would not recommend this since it's a backwards way of working, but if the initial value of your checked binding *has* to come from the input element itself, you could create a small binding handler that is executed before the `checked` binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['initChecked'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var checked = valueAccessor();
        if (element.checked) {
            checked(element.value);
        }
  }
};
```

Then bind like this:

```
<input id="DisbursementsOrTimeSheet_ChoiceField1" type="radio" name="DisbursementsOrTimeSheetChoice" value="Timesheet" data-bind="initChecked: paymentType, checked: paymentType" checked="checked">
```

It will work ([proof](https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/juv57etc/)). But the proper way to do this would be to get the data in the view model and, as someone well put it in the comments, cut out the middle man.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, The issue I've got is that I don't know which of the 2 radio button options will be selected when the page loads up (I'm using this in a form which is loading in data). Is there a way that I can check the "Checked" attribute of the Timesheet radio button when the page loads up?

Comment: @MikeP If the UI is dependent on data being loaded up, why not cut out the middle man and check that data to see which one is selected? That would make more sense than trying to get the checked attribute of a radio button.

Comment: Ideally, your form would consist of multiple observables that exist on your viewmodel. You would then load the form data in your viewmodel and update the observables accordingly. Then KO would handle the UI updates. But it sounds like your form is being generated and pre-populated server-side? If there's really no way to change that, you'd have to resort to manually checking the radio button values in the DOM.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a possible way of getting the initial `paymentType` value from the element itself, but really, avoid this if you can.

Comment: @BrotherWoodrow yeah the form is being pre-populated server side